# Как сайту получать данные о компьютере

Tags: javascript, python, html

Я не давно узнал о такой программе как Intel Driver & Support! И она работает таким образом:

1. Вы скачиваете программу и устонавливаете\
2. На сайте нажимаете кнопку \
3. Сайт получает все данные вашего пк

И я бы хотел узнать как это можно реолизовать на `python`, `html`, `javascript`?

Comment: Ни как. браузер не имеет доступа к этой информации. Собственно для того и ставится дополнительная программа, которая имеет полный доступ к ОС, может собрать ее с компа и через браузер (скорее всего через расширение) передать на свой сайт. Так что помимо перечисленных языков скорее всего надо основную часть написать на C++ или чем то подобном

Comment: Узнайте при помощи python информацию о системе и отправьте на сайт с помощью python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью свойства `appVersion`(объект `Navigator`) можно узнать версию браузера,
свойства `appName` – название браузера, свойства `appCodeName` – кодовое
название браузера, свойства `platform`– ОС, которую использует
пользователь.
Используется как-то так(с помощью
свойства `userAgent` можно вывести на страницу информацию о браузере
пользователя):

```
document.write('Информация о браузере:'+navigator.userAgent);
```

Насчет конкретно информации об ОС, кроме свойства `platform` я больше не знаю, увы.. Но может эта информация вам пригодится.